# Set button radius as a theme

Tags: java, android, button, themes, radius

```
<Button android:id="@+id/gp_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:onClick="gp"
    android:text="@string/go_gplay"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:theme="@style/ButonTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />    

<style name="ButonTheme" parent="ButonTheme">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#121212</item>
    <item name="android:topLeftRadius">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:bottomLeftRadius">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:topRightRadius">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:bottomRightRadius">20dp</item>
</style>
```

How can I edit button border radius as a theme, as you see i set the radius to 20dp and in preview it shows ok, but when compile and run it in phone it shows the radius by default.(i know the other "trick" to make a shape and then set it as button background, but in this way i will loose the "material" default animation)

Answer (score 0):

Make a drawable.. and then apply the drawables filename as a background to the `<Button>` within your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000" />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp" /> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topRightRadius="7dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting radius for whole corners , `<item name android:radius="20dp"/>`
or you maybe can put your button in a card view and curve it's corners. 
but the typical way is using shape.

Comment: It doesn't write like this : `<item name="android:radius">20dp</item>` ?And also not working, but maybe i'll try with "card view"